# Desabilitar a tecla ESC no windows com o Visual Basic ou Delphi

Tags: delphi, visual-basic-6

Como desabilitar o Esc no Windows via Visual Basic ou Delphi?

Quando o usuário está com o programa aberto o Esc fica inutilizável, não vai fazer ação em nenhum programa aberto.

Exemplo: com o menu iniciar aberto quando eu apertar Esc ele não vai fechar, não vai acontecer nada.

Pensei em fazer editando o registro do Windows e reiniciando a máquina, será que dá certo?

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: Tregistry;
begin
  Reg:=Tregistry.create;
  with Reg do
  begin
  rootkey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  OpenKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout', false);
  writestring('00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 5B E0 38 00 00 00 00 00', 'Scancode Map');
  closekey;
  end;
end;
```

Mas não consigo editar o registro assim...